# Voting to close a question makes it show as "on hold" even when it is not

Tags: bug, flags, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

I was checking the flagged posts, and I found one with a closing vote; I read it, and I agreed to vote to close it.

> [image: screenshot]

Right after I did it, the question was shown as on hold.

> [image: screenshot]

It is still open, right now. There are 3 closing votes, but the question is still open, so far.

> [image: screenshot]